# Using an onEdit Trigger on one spreadsheet to set values on another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on a time in/time out google sheet with a script.  My original question was how to share a sheet to a user(let's call them client) where the Client can edit the sheet that had an onEdit trigger that would then set values into another sheet that the Client did not have permission to use.

I first tried just sharing a spreadsheet and making one of the sheets in that spreadsheet locked.  But this prevented the trigger from running correctly when used by the client.   So I asked about it and someone suggested using an installable edit trigger on the client sheet.  And have the information be appended to a new spreadsheet. However, I don't think this is what I wanted because the way the code works needs the clients to not be able to edit the information that will be appended, not because I don't want false information but because if they get rid of certain columns, the script doesn't know what to do. 
But it did give me an idea, instead of having one spreadsheet with two sheets, just have 2 spreadsheets with 1 sheet each. Much less likely for the people using the client account to find the shared spreadsheet vs finding the sheet in the open spreadsheet they are using.

So now to show you some code.  Sorry I feel I have to show all of it due to any small thing that could be wrong I am over looking.

Host Spreadsheet Id is the Id of the spreadsheet the information is being logged into.  This is the information I don't want being edited by the client.
ACTIVE refers to the name of the sheet the client is clicking on and editing.  PASSIVE refers to the name of the sheet that is collecting information.  Originally these two sheets were on the same spreadsheet.

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getCurrentRow() {
  var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  return currentRow;
}


function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue()
}

function getNextRow() {
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Host Spreadsheet Id");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sas)
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PASSIVE').getLastRow() +1;

}
function getLasttRow() {
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Host Spreadsheet Id");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sas)
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PASSIVE').getLastRow();
}

function addRecord(a, b, c, d) {
      var sas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Host Spreadsheet Id");
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sas)
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('PASSIVE!A' + row, a);
  setValue('PASSIVE!B' + row, b);
  setValue('PASSIVE!C' + row, c);
  setValue('PASSIVE!D' + row, d);
}
/// this function is to find the row number(s) that match the criteria in
/// the timeIn() function so that the time in date can be placed 
/// directly to the right of the individual that signed out.
function findRows(c1,n1,c2,n2,c3,n3,name) {
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Host Spreadsheet Id")
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sas)
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][c1-1]==n1 && vA[i][c2-1]==n2 && vA[i][c3-1]==n3) {
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  return rA
}

function timeIn() {
  var row = getCurrentRow()
   var LocationA = getValue('ACTIVE!A' + row)
   var LocationB = getValue('ACTIVE!B' + row)
  var passiveRow = findRows(1,LocationA,2,LocationB,5,"",'PASSIVE');
  Logger.log(passiveRow);
  setValue('PASSIVE!E' + passiveRow, new Date().toLocaleString());
}

function places() {
   var row = getCurrentRow()
  addRecord(getValue('A' + row), getValue('B' + row), getValue('C' + row), new Date().toLocaleString());
}

function onEdit(e) {
   var row = getCurrentRow()
   var Location = getValue('ACTIVE!C' + row)
   var LocationA = getValue('ACTIVE!A' + row)
   var LocationB = getValue('ACTIVE!B' + row)
  var passiveRow = findRows(1,LocationA,2,LocationB,5,"",'PASSIVE');
  Logger.log(row)
  Logger.log(Location)
  Logger.log(LocationA)
  Logger.log(LocationB)
  Logger.log(passiveRow)
   if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "ACTIVE") return;
  if(Location !== 'HOME' && Location !== ""  && passiveRow == "") {
    places();
    Logger.log(passiveRow)
  }
 else if(Location !== 'HOME' && Location !== ""  && passiveRow !== "") {
    timeIn();
    places();
    Logger.log(passiveRow)

  }

  else if(Location === 'HOME' && passiveRow !== "") {
    timeIn(); 
    Logger.log(passiveRow)
} 
}
```

So this was my attempt at turning what used to be 2 sheets in the same spreadsheet into 2 different spreadsheets.  However, the `onEdit(e)` function doesn't work.  If I manually run the `timeIn()` function, it works and the `places()` function works as well.  Even goes and finds the last row of the spreadsheet it is importing information into.  But alas, when they edit Column C, the column that is suppose to activate the `onEdit(e)` if else to work, it doesn't run the functions.  What am I missing?

Let me give some visuals of what I'm trying to do. 
Here is the sheet the clients should see.  Column C has drop down boxes in each row full of locations.

```
  First  |   Last    | LOCATIONS
=================================
James    |   Carter  | HOME
Kyle     |  Johnson  | MALL
Micheal  |   Wilson  | BANK
Sarah    |   Smith   | HOME
Tray     |    Tin    | CLINIC
John     |   Becks   | HOME
```

Here would be the sheet collected by the Host Spreadsheet

```
  First  |   Last    | LOCATION |  OUT   |   IN
=====================================================
Tray     |    Tin    | CLINIC   |  10:00 |
James    |   Carter  | MALL     |  12:30 |  1:30
Kyle     |  Johnson  | MALL     |  12:45 |
Micheal  |   Wilson  | BANK     |  01:00 |
James    |   Carter  | POOL     |  01:30 |  2:00
```

I hope this is a good enough visual to get the point across as to what I'm trying to accomplish.  The code did work on the same spreadsheet, but now I'm trying to make it work on two in order to prevent the Client from messing with the Collected information.  Because if something like this happens :

```
  First  |   Last    | LOCATION |  OUT   |   IN
=====================================================
Tray     |    Tin    | CLINIC   |  10:00 |
James    |   Carter  | MALL     |  12:30 |  1:30
Kyle     |  Johnson  | MALL     |  12:45 |
Micheal  |   Wilson  | BANK     |  01:00 |
James    |   Carter  | POOL     |  01:30 |  2:00
Sarah    |   Smith   | POOL     |  01:30 |  
Sarah    |   Smith   | POOL     |  01:31 |
```

You see Sarah Smith is on twice with no Sign in.  This causes a bug because of how I get passive rows, it now sees 2 rows where "IN" is empty, so the function `findRows()` it gives me 2 values where I can only have 1 value in the function `setValue()` inside the `timeIn()` function.

Comment: Do you know where exactly your `onEdit()` is failing?

Comment: checking the logger.logs that I put under the```onEdit()``` all the values seem to be correct.  It's when it goes to the if else conditions and uses the ```places()``` or ```timeIn()``` functions.  They work fine when I run them manually while selecting a cell in the row to be got and transferred over to the Host sheet.   But when I edit that cell, to run the ```onEdit()``` function, nothing happens, but the logs do give the correct values. I did put an installable trigger and just made the ``onEdit()`` function the onEdit trigger. But kept coming back with " First Last Location" (the header)

Comment: I started doing more research on how it kept giving me first last location.  When onEdit gets to the if conditions and goes to ```places()```, the current row is correct, but when  ```places()``` starts the current row is changed to 1.  I don't know what is causing this. I put ``Logger.log(row)`` right under ```places()`` and it gave a 1.  This is if I put an installable trigger.  Without the installable trigger, it doesn't give anything.

Comment: You should get rid of basically all your `getActive----()` calls and instead use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) `e` available in your `onEdit()` function. Once you effectively use that parameter, you'll be able to remove a lot of the bloat that exists in your existing code.

Comment: I'm very new and don't know what that means.  How would the layout look with getting rid of the getActive's for the e?

Comment: Instead of `var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();` you would do `e.range.getRowIndex()`.

Comment: e was not defined.  Where would I put the functions?  Should they all be inside the onEdit function?

Comment: `e` will only be defined when you edit a the sheet. So to test, you'll have to go into the ACTIVE sheet and update the cell.

Comment: You appear to be using simple triggers instead of installable triggers. A simple rigger cannot access a spreadsheet besides the one it bound to and will not run.


Simple Triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
Installable triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: As far as installable triggers go.  I couldn't understand how the codes worked in conjunction with the code I already have.  I put an onEdit installable trigger that i tied to the onEdit function in the script.  Is that what I'm suppose to do?  It worked, but now the getcurrentrow function is always getting row 1.